# Dropbox Sync API invalid application

Tags: ios, dropbox-api

I have been developing an application in iOS using Dropbox Sync API, I am using the API to show a folder´s content in a table view. Today when I tried to sign in with my Dropbox account the modal showed me a message indicating that "The application is not valid". Does anyone knows whats going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=111173. Temporary issue, being fixed ASAP.